# What naming conventions are used for functions?

Tags: language-design

I thought there were patterns to how functions were named, but after looking carefully it seems I can always find exceptions. For instance

- FindThreshold = Action + Object
- SetAlphaChannel = Action + Object
- ReplaceImageValue = Action + Object

but... ImageResize = Object + Action, and why not ImageBinarize instead of Binarize?

Comment: There are some I find inconsistent. There's `Binarize` vs the non-existent `ImageBinarize`. There's the inconsistent pairs `FromCharacterCode`/`ToCharacterCode` vs `FromRomanNumeral`/`RomanNumeral`. Several "conversion" functions are `ToThing`, and several are just `Thing`: `ToString`, `ToUpperCase` vs `LetterNumber` and `SparseArray`. (In my mind, `SparseArray` is a conversion function, since the `InputForm` of a `SparseArray` object is of a very different format to the form in which one would usually input it.)

Comment: And why `FindPeaks` but `PeakDetect`? Perhaps consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds...

Comment: @bills, it does make a kind of sense. `FindThing` finds a thing (perhaps numerically) and returns the thing and its location. `ThingDetect` returns the original object but where the thing is highlighted.

Comment: @bills … although it might be A New Kind of Sense.

Comment: I think this is a great question and would vote to re-open it. Understanding the logic and principles that have gone into `System` names can IMO be of great assistance in being able to correctly guess a new/recalled function but also in designing your code. Perhaps it could be narrowed down to a request for some small set of principles used in such naming?

Comment: [Here](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2010/10/the-poetry-of-function-naming/) is Stephen Wolfram's blog on the naming of functions.

Comment: I agree with Ronald, It is a nice question, but the close reason is valid. It would of course be much better if a former or active WRI employee would stop by and share something from experience, but we shouldn't actively rely on that (hence the close reason again). @Sjoerd, perhaps your link with some excerpts from it would suffice as an answer too.

Answer (score 18):

You'll find plenty of exceptions if you keep looking — e.g. `MapThread` (action-action), `FileExtension` (object-object), `NIntegrate`, `NSolve` (Hungarian-like), etc.

I've always felt it's better to be more pragmatic about things like naming conventions as it allows for flexibility in the language design. I dare say it even improves readability at times, because it allows the designer to pause and reflect on how a symbol might be used and how it appears when read in code (as opposed to sticking to a naming dogma). In the case of image processing functions, I suppose the thought process was something like this:

- `Compose`, `Convolve`, `Histogram`, `Apply`, `Dimensions` are generically named functions that are also meaningful in the image processing context. But rather than overload these existing (possibly heavily optimized) functions to work on `_Image`, it makes sense to create separate symbols. So... `HistogramOfImage`? `ConvolveWithImage`? `ApplyOnImage`? A bit too verbose, even for *Mathematica*, and doesn't evoke the same simplicity as the parent functions.
- You then start using a prefix to common functions that immediately convey to the user what it does (because you're already familiar with the verb/noun) and what it acts on (the prefix) e.g. `ImageHistogram`, `ImageDimensions`, `ImageConvolve`, etc. This also helps disambiguate context specific uses of the noun/verb from generic ones.
- Once you do this, you've now already established sort of a soft convention that seems to fit well, so you then extend the idea to other symbols (but not necessarily based on pre-existing ones) such as `ImageCrop`, `ImageTrim`, `ImageResize`, `ImageData`, etc. The noun/verb conveys the meaning succinctly and can be used with other data types just as easily (e.g. `StringTrim`).
- Then finally you come to specialized functions which really have no use cases other than in image processing — `SetAlphaChannel`, `RemoveAlphaChannel`, `Opening`, `Closing`, etc. And now you've broken your own convention. And that's OK.

Could they have added an `Image-` prefix to all of these specialized functions for consistency? Yes. Should they have? Probably not, since it adds no additional information. Is it more readable as a result of not sticking to the rules? I would argue yes. If one must insist on consistency, then insisting on local consistency (within a specific package/functionality/group of functions) is better than insisting on global consistency.