# What's in a Name?

Tags: core-language, language-design, natural-language

`StringReplacePart["StringReplacePart","At",{14,17}]` ... Surely you can't be serious? ...

---

Naming Matters: I think what and how we call things is underestimated since not only does it immediately impact on codes` *readability* (or *decipherability*?), *recallability* and *autocompletability* but on deeper and growing connections between natural language and literate programming.

It has long puzzled me why, for example, `ReplacePart` was not named `ReplaceAt`. Three ovearching principles  relevant to finding a good name -  *Expressibility*, *Brevity* and *Consistency*, often represent competing tensions but for mine, `ReplaceAt` has got  `ReplacePart` covered on all three criteria. Of course, there may be some semantic sense, or logic I have overlooked but even the process of considering the principles behind `System` naming can, I think, improve one's own programming and efficiency. This [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90090/2249) delves into the principles behind `System` names (with a focus on linguistic senses) while this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19148/2249) gives some tips on user-defined names (in the broader context of what pitfalls to avoid) but I'm interested in further criteria that combine both.

While acknowledging the personal preference and potentially discursive nature of this question, my sense is that it would nonetheless be useful to posit a considered naming convention that while not absolute could still be usefully followed in the main. I'm looking for (<9) principles/rules/guidelines/tips for naming variables/functions (and which might encompass factors such as comparison/distinction with `System` functions, use of "palette symbols", linguistic/grammar sensibilities, length, capitalizations, context, user-experience, frequency etc). Naturally, answers themselves exhibiting  *Expressability*, *Brevity* and *Consistency* will be preferred.

---

... Well yes I am (and don't call me Shirley ... with apologies to Dr. Rumack)

Comment: Have you been playing with the package ``Experimental`MindAlteringDrugs` ``? What is the question here?

Comment: @ciao has a point. Anyway, this has been discussed before. A good suggestion [then](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1112/pg1112-images.html) was: "... That which we call a rose / By any other name would smell as sweet."

Comment: @ciao Possibly, but yes suspect a closure is on the cards. Think there is a useful question lurking in there but oh well

Comment: A classier name for `StringReplacePart` would be `StringYoureFired`. Regards, D. Trump.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: @ciao In case you haven't them, the docs are [**here**](http://www.amazon.com/Doors-Perception-Heaven-Thinking-Classics/dp/1907590099/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1439433415&sr=1-1&keywords=the+doors+of+perception)

Comment: I can't quite figure out where you're going with this so I'll just comment on the one concrete example I see.  I would expect `ReplaceAt` to perform a `Replace` operation "at" a particular position, whereas I would expect `ReplacePart` to directly replace a particular part of of an expression.  So at least at first blush your simplification would add confusion, IMHO.  A complicated issue to be sure but I'm not sure it can properly addressed on this site.

Comment: Well I suppose the `Part` in `StringPart` has different semantics (actual structure) from the `Part` in `ReplacePart` (position in structure) which allows their similar form even with different meanings. Of course, as pointed out by @ciao and @Jens no such issue arises while working in an alternative context since the analogous `Experimental`MindalteringDrugs`Trump`YoureFired` and `Experimental`MindalteringDrugs`Trump`StringYoureFired` have less conflict.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard beat me to this exact point by seconds - yes better to let this one go through to the keeper